# Prolog error arguments

Tags: list, error-handling, prolog, iso-prolog, error-checking

I'm wondering how to go about adding error checking in Prolog.
For instance I have a program that will find how long a list is:

```
listlen([],0). 
listlen([_|T],N) :-
   listlen(T,X),
   N is X+1.
```

How would I print out an error like "The 1st argument has to be a list" when it happens?

Comment: In this particular case, there are good reasons to not produce an error. See [this comparison](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/length) for the behavior of various systems in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

SWI-Prolog has [ISO-compliant exception handling](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=exception), so you can actually throw errors [as defined in the standard](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/error_k#error_classes).

```
?- throw(error(type_error(list, foo), context(foo/0, 'Must be a list'))).
ERROR: foo/0: Type error: `list' expected, found `foo' (an atom) (Must be a list)
```

This is not only difficult to type/use: it is also implementation dependent. Instead, you can (and should) use [library(error)](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=error), which provides the [`must_be/2` predicate](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=must_be/2) (sadly, it is very difficult to find this on the SWI-Prolog website if you don't know what you are looking for):

```
?- must_be(list, [foo]).
true.

?- must_be(list, foo).
ERROR: Type error: `list' expected, found `foo' (an atom)
```

I assume that other Prolog implementations that support exception handling provide very similar facilities.

Comment: There is another reason why writing `throw(error(E,Imp_def))` is problematic: The second argument of `error/2` is implementation defined. So code that gives an explicit term that is not specific to an ISO conforming  implementation may not work.

Comment: @false Yes. Actually, it is quite difficult (because documentation) to figure out the exact "ISO error term definition".

Comment: You know [this](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/error_k#error_classes)?

Comment: @false no I did not. This is a great reference, thank you.